# android: Custom Submenus

Tags: java, android, xml, menu, submenu

I want to create a customized submenu where i can add an "about page" to my application. So my submenu would just be a text view with a bunch of info. Im currently defining my menu in XML. Any help or links would be great, thanks!!!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/settings_menu"
    android:title="Settings" />
<item android:id="@+id/about_menu"
    android:title="About">
    <menu>
        <item android:id="@+id/about_submenu"
            android:title="Tip Message" />
    </menu>
</item>
<item android:id="@+id/quit_menu"
    android:title="Quit" />
</menu>
```

Also just out of curiosity, how would i define a more complex custom submenu, like one that takes user input from a keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's easier to make something look like a menu. Try `Activity` with `@android:drawable/menu_submenu_background` as a background for example.